# Return value from previous cell conditionally

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to return a value from a previous cell if the cell to the left of it (on the same row) is X.

[image]

For all rows with 115 in A column, I want to put the formula in column C, to get the value from the 1st previous cell in column B for which column A shows 20.

Comment: comment from bjoeran1 who raised the question orginally - It is in Excel 2010 - not 2013

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: @bjoeran1 You can always [edit] and fix the tags yourself. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, for exmple for `C1`:

```
=IF(A1=115,LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)-1,2))=20),B:B),"")
```